# Interger not registering in my while or statment?

Tags: java, while-loop, integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class EnterPIN1
 {
 public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pin = 12345;
    int pintwo = 54321;
    
    

    System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE BANK OF MITCHELL.");
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
    int entry = keyboard.nextInt();

    while ( entry != pin ) || (entry != pintwo )
    {
        System.out.println("\nINCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN.");
        System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
        entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("\nPIN ACCEPTED. YOU NOW HAVE ACCESS TO YOUR ACCOUNT.");
 }
}
```

Hello all! I am tasked with making an ATM pin system, I have two pins so far that I am using, 12345 and 54321. The first pin works flawlessly and works correctly in the program whereas the other dosent register as a "correct pin". I am new to java so I dont know if this is because I have both seperate in different interger values or because I have them set up incorrectly in my while statement. Any help would be apperciated!

Comment: Hint: under what conditions is `( entry != pin ) || (entry != pintwo )` true?  Don't read what you intended it to do, step through what it actually does.  Try some examples.

Comment: `||` means "or" in Java, so the statement `( entry != pin ) || (entry != pintwo )` is always true since entry is bound to not be one or the other, you need to use `&&` for conditions where you need both to be true in this case that `entry` doesn't match either.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I propose.

```
while (( entry != pin ) && (entry != pintwo ))
{
    System.out.println("\nINCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN.");
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
    entry = keyboard.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("\nPIN ACCEPTED. YOU NOW HAVE ACCESS TO YOUR ACCOUNT.");
```

}

entry can not be equal to pin and pintwo at the same time.That makes your statement always true.I think you should use &&(and) instead of ||(or)
}

Comment: Added and updated the code, it dosent seem to like the && statement or ||. Not sure if I have done something wrong with my integers or if my formatting is making it run in a certain way that's just not working.

Comment: I tried your code in my IDE with the solution I propose and it works.Please,just copy and paste the above solution.If it's not working,let me know

Comment: Still doesnt seem to be working for me I am using Notepad++ as my IDE so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler ,use this online compiler to check if your code could compile.  for while statement don't forget to use global brackets, I mean while (     (entry!=pin) && (entry !=pintwo) )

Comment: That worked! thank you very much, something must be wrong with my notepad++ Ill have to toy with it, thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget to vote /accept  my answer. It will encourage me to help others too.Thanks !For IDE,you can use Eclipse or Intelli J,it could help you more